# http get woks in Postman but fails in chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, http, postman

same url, http get, postman works and return 200.

copy the url into Chrome, return 500.

The request header differs in postman and chrome, but I am not sure about that and I can't verify this by modifying the request header in chrome.
[Postman request header and return 200](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GzCxk.png)

[Chrome request header but return 500](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFAhh.png)

Answer (score 0):

Url seems to be different.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFAhh.png --> has '/1' (url path)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GzCxk.png --> has '/2' (url path)

Can you check, if same is happening in '/1` in postman